Aspire project fails to load image of Blazor page
Problem:  New .NET Aspire Starter App project with copied working Razor page that displays image fails to show image on button press.  Why?
Steps to Reproduce:
Background - requires .NET Aspire module loaded into Visual Studio.

Download and verify that Blazor Samples runs its ShowImage2 razor page fine correctly displaying an image when a button is pressed:
https://github.com/dotnet/blazor-samples/

Create new project => ".NET Aspire Starter App" template and just took the defaults.

Copy ShowImage2.razor into the project from Step 1 or from one of these 2 links:
https://github.com/dotnet/blazor-samples/blob/main/8.0/BlazorSample_WebAssembly/Pages/ShowImage2.razor
https://github.com/dotnet/blazor-samples/blob/main/9.0/BlazorSample_WebAssembly/Pages/ShowImage2.razor


I placed this ShowImage2.razor code in C:\Users\XXXX\source\repos\AspireApp1\AspireApp1.Web\Components\Pages with the other razor pages.

Adjust NavMenu.razor found in Layout directory so can reach the new page. I did by:
     <div class="nav-item px-3">
     <NavLink class="nav-link" href="show-image-2">
         <span class="bi bi-list-nested" aria-hidden="true"></span> Show Image2
     </NavLink>
 </div>


Run and verify that the new page fails to show the image on the button press.  (Aspire requires clicking on Resources then webfrontend line and either endpoint to see the running web page.)

So question is "Why?" does it fail?


PS - (You can add alt="null" property to the img tag to clarify things.)
Maybe I need to add a @rendermode that the old Blazor applications did not need? Maybe some external piece to the ShowImage page needs something turned on?


Maybe I need to add a @rendermode that the old Blazor applications did
not need? Maybe some external piece to the ShowImage page needs
something turned on?

Yes, you need add the @rendermode from .NET 8.
As the official document said, the default rendermode would be Static Server, no event support.
To add interactive support (events), you can add @rendermode InteractiveServer in your component.
Update:
Be sure add the js code in App.razor which locates in C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\AspireApp1\AspireApp1.Web\Components\App.razor:
<body>
    <Routes />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.setSource = async (elementId, stream, contentType, title) => {
            const arrayBuffer = await stream.arrayBuffer();
            let blobOptions = {};
            if (contentType) {
                blobOptions['type'] = contentType;
            }
            const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], blobOptions);
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const element = document.getElementById(elementId);
            element.title = title;
            element.onload = () => {
                URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            }
            element.src = url;
        }
    </script>
</body>


Thank you Rena for some direction.  I feel this gets me closer.  I added  @rendermode InteractiveServer to ShowImage2.razor.  Now when I press the button, I get "An unhandled error has occurred. Reload.".  So I inspected in browser to dig for error.  Then I added comma and "DetailedErrors": true to appsettings.json for better errors.  Now I see "Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'setSource' ('setSource' was undefined)." . Googling does not help. Notice that Program.cs already has builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
.AddInteractiveServerComponents();

Hi @Eric Wood, Please check my updated answer if you add the correct js code in your project

Hi @Rena, Added script to App.razor.  Still fails to display. No visible errors now.  this.requestMonitor is undefined in browser errors.

Hi @Eric Wood, there is no code about this.requestMonitor in my shared code. Maybe you add any other code which I do not know. Pls check the browser error and click the error to check the error location and share enough code. Or you can create a new .NET Aspire Starter App project then copy the ShowImage2.razor code and change the App.razor like my answer did.

Hi @Rena, No this.requestMonitor code in my code either. That is what confused me.  Will attempt to rebuild again from scratch.

Hi @Rena, Still no luck.  So you see the image after your adjustment?

Hi @EricWood, Yes. I only change the file path cause my network policy that cannot access that url.  For example:await Http.GetStreamAsync("https://localhost:7226/favicon.png");. 7226 is the AspireApp1.Web request port numbet, favicon.png is the default existing image in AspireApp1.Web/wwwroot.
